# Regarding Alt+x in zsh and how to bind Alt+x to something else

Tags: zsh

When I type `Alt-x`, `execute:` will pop up:

```
~ % 
execute: _
```

And I can continue type(space has no effect):

```
~ %        
execute: what'sthis
```

Q1: what's this promotion for?

Q2: How can i modify this shortcut to other key-binding? Because `M-x` in emacs is quite useful, and i use shell in emacs often, so the two conflict.

I have google for hours, but still have no answers(maybe my keywords are not correct--*google: "zsh" + "excute:"*, *"google: zsh keybinding bindkey*

Comment: Instead of using an advertising search engine for hours, read the Z shell user manual.  The information in M. Chazelas's answer is all in there, M. Chazelas even referring you directly to some of it, and can be found in a far shorter time than "hours".

Comment: Thanks for your advice :) I also find RTFM is quite worthwhile yesterday.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you do:

```
bindkey | grep -F '^[x'
```

or simply:

```
bindkey '^[x'
```

or if in doubt about how to express Alt+x:

```
bindkey | grep -w x
```

You'll see:

```
"^[x" execute-named-cmd
```

That's the name of the widget bound to  ESC x and most terminals send the ESC x character sequence upon pressing <kbd>Alt+x</kbd>

```
info zsh execute-named-cmd
```

Will tell you what that widget does (you may need to install the `zsh-doc` package on some systems).

As the name suggests, it prompts for  a command to execute. Commands here being zsh widgets, editor commands. That's the equivalent of `emacs`' <kbd>Meta-x</kbd>, except that it's zsh editor commands instead of `emacs` command  (the command is called `execute-extended-command` in `emacs`)

For instance, if at that prompt, you type `backward-delete-char` and press <kbd>Return</kbd>, it will invoke that widget which by default is bound to <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. You can do exactly the same in `emacs`.

If instead, you type `desc`<kbd>Tab</kbd> (<kbd>Tab</kbd> for completing it into `describe-key-briefly`, a widget not bound to any key by default, and also found in `emacs`) and press <kbd>Return</kbd>, you'll see another prompt:

```
$
Describe key briefly: _
```

Where you can press, say, <kbd>Alt+x</kbd> to see what that's bound do. You'd then get:

```
"^[x" is execute-named-cmd
```

If you do the same in `emacs`, you'll see:

```
M-x runs the command execute-extended-command
```

To see the list of widgets, run `zle -al`, `zle -l` for the non-builtin ones, `bindkey` to list the key bindings.

You can bind <kbd>Alt+x</kbd> to something else with

```
bindkey "^[x" some-widget
```

Comment: There's no need to `grep` the output of `bindkey`.  `bindkey '^[x'` also works.

Comment: @JdeBP, good point. See edit.

Comment: `bindkey "^[^x"` worked for me.

Comment: @strboul. Weird. What terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas sorry, correcting myself. `^[x` works not `^[^x`.